# Dazed and confused - is this your preferred way to handle controllers in ipad apps?

Tags: iphone, ipad, controller, navigation

Just getting started with iphone and ipad apps.  Lots of reading, lots of tinkering, but I think I'm still missing a basic concept

General Question: Assume you're creating an **ipad** app where you want 1/2 of a view to be a nav controller.  Do you find yourself:

A) Creating a UIView, add tableview, add navigation bar, etc... and hookup up all the plumbing manually.

OR

B) Creating a navigation controller and adding it as a subview (if this is possible)

I'm trying to understand how experienced ipad developers make apps (like ipod,  where the screen is broken up into distinct areas, with some being tableviewcontrollers, nav controllers...)

Thanks for reading this.  All inputs appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a navigation controller, then push a tableview controller onto the navigation controller. It seems you have some qualms about doing this in particular, but I'm not quite sure which part you're shaky about.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I was shaky as I didn't see how you could add nav controllers to another subview, but it's starting to make sense now.

Comment: In terms of UIViewControllers and the UI part, you should just think of them as just UIViews with the ability for extra functionality. That means you can still use the view part just like as you would any other view. It just might happen to have some extra logic stuff that sets it apart from your average UIView that displays something.

Comment: Although it seems obvious now, I was not making the connection that you could grab the view property of a controller and use it like any other view.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Where possible, UIViews should be 'abstracted' from application logic so option A will be a bad idea almost every time.

How you architect your App will depend on its specific requirements but in general this is how you will see things structured:

DEVICE WINDOW -> NAV/TAB BAR CONTROLLER -> (TABLE)VIEW CONTROLLER(S) -> SUBVIEWS (UIVIEWS)

This is a good read for you, in case you haven't seen it yet http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, i recall reading it about a month ago when I first got started, but reading it again with a little knowledge certainly helps.

Comment: I guess what was adding to my confusion was the misconception that you couldn't add a nav controller in IB in a nib file for view controller, so you would have to make up the parts individually or do it in code.  I was trying to drag into the view :(

Comment: Yeah I appreciate it can be a bit daunting at first but it will eventually start making sense to you :) I can see you're new to the community so if you're satisfied with any of the answers you should mark your question as responded.